# Can't install dropbox on Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, dropbox

Downloaded the Dropbox `.deb` on a fresh Xubuntu 22.04 install and tried

```shell
sudo dpkg -i dropbox_2022.12.05_amd64.deb
```

This is the result:

```shell
(Reading database ... 193177 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dropbox_2022.12.05_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dropbox (2022.12.05) over (2022.12.05) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dropbox:
 dropbox depends on libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.8.0); however:
  Version of libgtk-4-1:amd64 on system is 4.6.6+ds-0ubuntu1.
 dropbox depends on gir1.2-gtk-4.0 (>= 4.8.0); however:
  Package gir1.2-gtk-4.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dropbox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dropbox
```

Version `>=4.8.0` of  `libgtk-4-1` only seems to be available for Xubuntu 22.10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install the previous version of dropbox if you don't plan to update Ubuntu to 22.10.

The following online directory holds various Dropbox's releases for Ubuntu: https://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/pool/main/

The dropbox_2020.03.04_amd64.deb version works well with Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Please add additional information beyond only a link. Thanks.

Comment: @ArturMeinild as the link is to the Dropbox linux repositories for the "older version" downloads, I think this link is OK.  But answer poster SHOULD  add more info on how to use this link, what to download, how to install what they download, etc.

Comment: Downloading the `dropbox_2020.03.04_amd64.deb` fixed it for me.